# Using JUnit temporary folders and checking file existence on system exit

Tags: java, junit, system-rules

I have a unit test like this, using

[`org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.ExpectedSystemExit`](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/apidocs/org/junit/contrib/java/lang/system/ExpectedSystemExit.html)

[`org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html)

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Rule
public final ExpectedSystemExit exit = ExpectedSystemExit.none();


@Test
public void createsFile_integrationTest() throws Exception{

    final File tempFolder = folder.newFolder("temp");

    exit.expectSystemExitWithStatus(0);
    exit.checkAssertionAfterwards(new Assertion() {

        @Override
        public void checkAssertion() throws Exception {
            assertTrue(new File(tempFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/created-file.txt").exists());

        }

     main.run(tempFolder.getAbsolutePath() +"/created-file.txt"); 

    });
```

The problem with this, is that the temporary folder starts tearing down as soon as it gets system exit, and not after my `checkAssertion()` is called.

Is there a way I can prevent my temporary folder tear down until the end of checkAssertion?

**Edit:** I think what the answer is - is to do a refactor and separate these to two tests - one where I test system exit, and the other where I test file creation.

Comment: What happens if you switch the order of `expectSystemExitWithStatus()` and `checkAssertionAfterwards()`? I'm not sure what `checkAssertionAfterwards()` does, but from what you are doing here it seems to only register a callback. Do you know when this callback is actually executed?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I did try that - it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enforce an order on the rules so that the `ExpectedSystemExit` rule can check the assertion before `TemporaryFolder` is shutdown. You can use JUnit's [RuleChain](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html) for this.

```
private final TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
private final ExpectedSystemExit exit = ExpectedSystemExit.none();

@Rule
public TestRule chain = RuleChain.outerRule(folder).around(exit);

@Test
public void createsFile_integrationTest() throws Exception {

    final File tempFolder = folder.newFolder("temp");

    exit.expectSystemExitWithStatus(0);
    exit.checkAssertionAfterwards(new Assertion() {

        @Override
        public void checkAssertion() throws Exception {
            assertTrue(new File(tempFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/created-file.txt").exists());

        }
    });

    main.run(tempFolder.getAbsolutePath() +"/created-file.txt"); 

}
```